# Hostgator Dedicated Server to Amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, dedicated-server, dedicated-hosting

I am currently hosting at hostgator using their dedicated server paying $219 monthly. One of my friend recommend transferring to Amazon ec2.

My question is, can amazon do the same thing as hostgator like serving unlimited domain?
Additionally, I have around 650 GB monthly bandwidth and I am using mostly Drupal and WordPress on my different websites. What is the equivalent of dedicated server from hostgator if I plan to transfer?

BTW, he told me that the medium that is priced around $165 per month is the best choice. Is this a good idea of transferring from hostgator to Amazone ec2?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is... it all depends.

You'd need to check out Amazon's [pricing calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html) to see what kind of money you'd be looking to spend using data from your current server.

I would encourage you first to create a micro instance (which is free for a year), try it all out, get familiar with at least S3, EC2, EBS, RDS, and CloudFront from Amazon AWS, and then use the calculator to see if it's going to save you money in the long run. Being able to adjust your server speed is REALLY nice for optimizing pricing though...

Note: AWS can be a little overwhelming when you first get on it. There are a lot of three letter adjective services, but if you give it some time, you'll start to really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

EC2 is tough for people who used cPanel. Unless you have a dedicated tech guy managing the site, you do not want to choose Ec2.

Its worth spending money for cPanel,(host gator like) than reading 100s of help forum post to troubleshoot your server issue.

Ec2 is great if you are a great techie and have enough time..